# How to clear QwtPlot curves before replotting?

Tags: c++, qt, qwt

In the earlier versions of `Qwt` we add `QwtPlot::clear()` but now, I can't find it.

Any ideas? I have a real time plot, so when replotting, the info before xmin is not really important and with time it crashes as the replot is replotting all the information before xmin.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The method `Qwtplot::clear()` has been deprecated. Use `QwtPlotDict::detachItems` instead.

```
void QwtPlotDict::detachItems(int rtti = QwtPlotItem::Rtti_PlotItem, 
                              bool autoDelete = true 
                             )
```

Parameters:

> **rtti**: In case of QwtPlotItem::Rtti_PlotItem detach all items otherwise only those items of the type rtti. 
>   **autoDelete**: If true, delete all detached items

Comment: well, I used this `            for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
            {
                plot_all[i]->detachItems(QwtPlotItem::Rtti_PlotItem, true);
                plot[i]->detachItems(QwtPlotItem::Rtti_PlotItem, true);
            }`and it didn's detach the `QwtCurves`

Comment: what happens when you call the function with no arguments? Like plot_all[i]->detachItems();

Answer (score 2):

one of the way to clear plot is to set your data points to empty:
for example:
(m_vctTime,m_vctValue -vector)
(curve=new QwtPlotCurve())
(plot=new QwtPlot(parent))

```
m_vctTime.clear();
m_vctValue.clear();
curve->setSamples(m_vctTime,m_vctValue);
plot->replot();
```

that clears your plot